# Area beyond horizontal scroll range set to body colour

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS.  I want a horizontal strip of the screen to be black, on a red background.  Using CSS, I define a wrapper with a black background and a body with a red background.

Unfortunately, when there's a horizontal scrollbar, the wrapper only takes up the part of the page that can be seen with the scrollbar at the extreme left.  The area of the page to the right of this is entirely red.

Here is the relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page" class="container">
        <div id="content">
            <h2 class="title">Foo</h2>
            <div class="Body">
                <p>Bar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>



#wrapper {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#page {
    padding-top: 280px;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the minimum width for div #wrapper

```
#wrapper {
          min-width: 1000px;
         }
```